# How to check if values in an array is exists in an array in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've searched over the internet but nothings seems to be the same with my problem. What I want is to add `question numbers` for the questions in `text` field, and numbers should be `unique`. I'm trying to check if the `array of numbers` is exists in an array of number of questions `(e.g. 8 questions)`, then if it is in array, you can enter the number as long as it is `not entered yet`, but my code is not working. How can I do that? Please see my code below for reference.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var try1;
  var arrayLen = $('#question\\[\\]').length;
  var numArray = [];
  var convertedArray;
  for(i = 1; i <= arrayLen; i++){
   numArray.push(i);
  }
  
  $('#question\\[\\]').on('input', function(){
    if($.inArray($(this).val(), numArray) !== -1){
     $('#result').html("available");
    } else{
     $("#result").html("not available");
      return false;
    }
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="description"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="question[]" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>

<span id="result"></span>
```

**Accepted Answer:** *but needs an UPDATE*

[Accepted answer by @Shiladitya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45950906/how-to-check-if-values-in-an-array-is-exists-in-an-array-in-jquery-javascript#answer-45951078)

Comment: IDs must be unique. `$('#question\\[\\]')` will only select the first element with that ID. However, there is no reason why these elements should have IDs. Use a different selector to select them. The other problem will be that `$(this).val()` returns a *string* while your array contains numbers. `"10"` and `10` are not considered equal by `$.inArray` (as the documentation explicitly points out).

Comment: `$('#question\\[\\]')` returns the current input, anyways, can you write your answer ?

Comment: @Jonjie The numbers in the question array are `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`? Or are they 8 uniques numbers entered by the user? And how is the other array of numbers? Could you provide an example of these actual arrays that need to be compared to each other?

Comment: @zer00ne `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` is the number of item `(number of questions)`. The other array is the `current input` where you entered the number, so it is basically checking if it is exists in the array, then if it is, you can enter that number, `BUT` you can only enter it if it is not yet entered in the other field.

Comment: @Jonjie so if the user enters 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, they can't go back and enter anything, correct?

Comment: @zer00ne in 1 field? no, the user can only enter 1 number `(e.g. 2 or 3 or 1)` each field, as long as the number is in the array of items `([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])`. And the number that will be entered should be unique

Comment: @Jonjie So any number 1 thru 8 can be entered into each field in any order. You can only use a number once.

Comment: @zer00ne Exactly Sir! you got it. Can you provide your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/33zeL2fa/5/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arrayLen = $('input[name="question[]"]').length;
  var numArray = [];
  for(i = 1; i <= arrayLen; i++){
   numArray.push(i);
  }

  $('input[name="question[]"').keypress(function(e){
    if(numArray.indexOf(parseInt(e.key)) != -1){
      $('#result').html("available");
      numArray.splice(numArray.indexOf(parseInt(e.key)), 1);
    } else{
      $("#result").html("not available");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="description"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>

<span id="result"></span>
```

I've used `jQuery keydown` event.

**More Update with validation**
Her you go https://jsfiddle.net/33zeL2fa/6/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var try1;
  var arrayLen = $('input[name="question[]"]').length;
  var numArray = [];
  var convertedArray = [];
  for(i = 1; i <= arrayLen; i++){
   numArray.push(i);
  }

  $('input[name="question[]"').keydown(function(e){

   if(e.which === 8 || e.keyCode === 8){
     numArray.push(parseInt($(this).attr('newval')));
      $(this).removeAttr('newval');
    } else {
      if(numArray.indexOf(parseInt(e.key)) != -1){
        $('#result').html("available");
        $(this).attr('newval', e.key);
        numArray.splice(numArray.indexOf(parseInt(e.key)), 1);
      } else{
        $("#result").html("not available");
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="shortAnswer"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="description"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="multipleChoice"><br><br>
<input type="text" name="question[]" placeholder="trueFalse"><br><br>

<span id="result"></span>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Jonjie Here you go with an update https://jsfiddle.net/33zeL2fa/9/ . Solution without `maxlength` attribute. Sorry for replying late.